# Filtering search results

Tags: categories, search, woocommerce-offtopic

I have pages, posts and woocommerce product categories and products in my website. I want to limit wordpress default search query so that it returns the posts, the pages, the product categories but **NOT** individual products. I am using the following code in my `functions.php` with which I can easily show only posts and pages. What I need now, is to show the woocommerce product categories along with my posts and pages in the search result, but **NOT** the individual products. Please help me out here.

```
function searchfilter($query) {

if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
    $query->set('post_type',array('post','page'));
}

return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```

Comment: I got that wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to include a tax_query for the Woocommerce taxonomy (called 'product_cat'):

```
    $tax_query = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
        ),
    );
    $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );   
}

return $query;
}
```

However, you'll have to ensure that you can return posts AND pages AND product categories and also note the search results will be mixed up together.

I would have thought a better solution, rather than filtering at functions.php level, would be to adapt your search.php for the display of the search results. You can then be quite targeted, for instance show:

```
Posts with this search include:
PostX, PostY, PostZ.
```

And then another loop with:

```
Pages with this search include:
PageA, PageB, PageC.
```

And then another loop with:

```
Product Categories with this search include:
Product Cat A, Product Cat F, Product Cat Z.
```

Is that the kind of result you are after, or would you like to filter EVERY search on your site and mix up the results?

Comment: Thanks @Monkey Puzzle :) .. I will try your solution tomorrow and get back to you :)...cheers

Comment: ahh..mixing up things will create problem I think...can you please elaborate how do I implement your second solution in my search.php file ? currently there is only one while loop in that file...however I will also implement your first solution just for testing purpose...you modified your code above..i will include your code into mine and check whether its feasible for me or not...thanks anyway...

Comment: btw, your first solution doesn't work :(

Comment: Yeah, I realised that would have filtered out everything to ONLY show product_cats, and of course you can't have posts which are product_cats, so it won't show anything. Sorry about that. You'd need to reword it so it shows pages AND posts AND product_cats, but I don't think you could easily separate them and the results would be all mixed up.

Comment: To get multiple loops on the search results page, you could follow a tutorial [like this one](http://blog.mikeeverleth.com/multiple-loops-on-wordpress-search-results-templates/). You end up getting a very nice clean display of results which you can format any way you like.

Comment: so what should be the : $search_query = array( /* CUSTOM LOOP PARAMETERS GO HERE */ ); for PAGES,POSTS AND PRODUCT CATEGORIES in this case ??? can you please help me out here and provide me 3 search queries that I am looking for :)

Comment: $search_query = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' ); shows all the products, but not the category names....i want the opposite one...it should show category names but not the products...help me out with the query please...

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter_exc_posts');
function search_filter_exc_posts($query) {
    // Verify that we are on the search page & this came from the search form
    if($query->query_vars['s'] != '' && is_search())
    {
        $q_tax_query = $query->query_vars["tax_query"];
        // append product categories to current tax query.
        $query->set('tax_query', $q_tax_query[]=array('taxonomy'=>'product_cat') );
    }
}
```